# How do I change the page title from Dynamic Data Site in the Visual Studio Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-dynamic-data

I create a Dynamic Data Site from a Template in Visual Studio 2010. The Page title says "Dynamic Data Site." How do I change this?

Thanks,
CJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in `<h1 Class="DDMainHeader">Dynamic Data Site</h1>` in the **Site.master** file.

The sub heading "My Tables" can changed in the **Default.aspx** page in the `<h2 class="DDSubHeader>My Tables</h2>` line.